# How do we handle Microsoft Azure mobile OTP in Jmeter?

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, loadrunner, jmeter-maven-plugin, totp

I tried to record an application which uses Microsoft Azure Totp. I couldn't handle otp. Please help.

Unable to disable toptp

Answer (score 0):

You can generate a TOTP using i.e. [this library](https://github.com/taimos/totp), the relevant [JSR223 Test Element](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223) and some [Groovy code](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-groovy):

[image]

Comment: Hi @Dmitri T 
Thank you!!
I would like to get the real time otp which is sent to my mobile number during login on my application which uses microsoft authentication. Any leads will be helpful